# Why need to specify activesheet for chartobjects.add

Tags: vba

```
Sub smarterway()
    Dim chartfirst As ChartObject
    Dim rngChart As Range
    Set rngChart = Range("D3:J20")

    Set chartfirst = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rngChart.Left, Top:=rngChart.Top, Width:=rngChart.Width, Height:=rngChart.Height)
[....]
```

For this line:

> Set chartfirst = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(..)

if I dont add in *Activesheet* in. I get a *Object Required* error.

I don't understand why though. Isnt it assumed it is Activesheet, cause I usually don't put Activesheet in my codes and it works as long as I have the required sheet opened and activated.

I'm clearly missing and misunderstanding something very fundamental in vba, please advice

Comment: ChartObjects is a collection associated with a worksheet. It's not an Application-level item

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? so the hierarchy is something like Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheets.Range("A1").Value. And usually when im working on a worksheet (it is currently active) I can just do Range("A1").value. So in this case with chartObjects why doesnt it work? Why do we have to specify Activesheet, when usually it just assume it is there? or am I misunderstanding something here

Comment: `ActiveSheet` is a property of the `Application` object, since there can be only one per instance of Excel.  `Range()` *typically* defaults to the Active sheet, but if it's in a sheet code module it defaults to that sheet.  It's good practice however to never use `Range()` without qualifying it with a worksheet object: unqualified Range objects make your code brittle and difficult to debug.